# Pig 0.11.0 not sorting before applying DISTINCT

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have some records that contain some bags as fields and I'm trying to merge the bags for records that have otherwise identical fields (I am discarding some fields).

The data looks something like:

```
u08 u08an   id  {(web)} 0   0   {(GB),(US)} an
u08 u08an   id  {(ars)} 0   0   {(GB),(RU)} an
u09 u09an   id  {(web)} 0   0   {(GB)}  an
u09 u09an   id  {(web)} 0   0   {(US)}  an
u10 u10an   id  {(web)} 0   0   {(GB)}  an
u10 u10an   id  {(ars)} 0   0   {(GB)}  an
u11 u11an   id  {(web)} 0   0   {(GB)}  an
u11 u11an   id  {(web)} 0   0   {(GB)}  an
```

and I would like to obtain (after discarding irrelevant fields and shuffling) something like:

```
u08 u08an   an  {(GB),(US),(RU)}
u09 u09an   an  {(GB),(US)}
u10 u10an   an  {(GB)}
u11 u11an   an  {(GB)}
```

The input is loaded using the following schema:

```
user_identities = LOAD '$partner_user_identities_location' AS (
    user_id: chararray,
    partner_user_id: chararray,
    partner_user_id_type: chararray,
    sync_types: bag{tuple(chararray)},
    synced_first_timestamp: double,
    synced_last_timestamp: double,
    country_codes: bag{tuple(chararray)},
    partner_id: chararray
);
```

If I'm merging both `sync_types` and `country_codes`, everything works as expected, but if I only generate `country_codes`, the records are not sorted before applying `DISTINCT`, so non-adjacent duplicates remain in the output.

Running the following snippet (in local mode):

```
user_identities = GROUP user_identities BY (user_id, partner_user_id, partner_id);

user_identities = FOREACH user_identities {
    sync_types = FOREACH user_identities GENERATE flatten(sync_types);
    sync_types = DISTINCT sync_types;

    country_codes = FOREACH user_identities GENERATE flatten(country_codes);
    country_codes = DISTINCT country_codes;

    GENERATE flatten(group) AS (user_id, partner_user_id, partner_id), sync_types, country_codes;
}

DUMP user_identities;
```

Outputs:

```
(u08,u08an,an,{(ars),(web)},{(GB),(RU),(US)})
(u09,u09an,an,{(web)},{(GB),(US)})
(u10,u10an,an,{(ars),(web)},{(GB)})
(u11,u11an,an,{(web)},{(GB)})
```

However, if I change the inner `GENERATE` statement to `GENERATE flatten(group) AS (user_id, partner_user_id, partner_id), country_codes;`, omitting `sync_types`, I get the following output (note the duplicate `(GB)` in the first record):

```
(u08,u08an,an,{(GB),(RU),(GB),(US)})
(u09,u09an,an,{(GB),(US)})
(u10,u10an,an,{(GB)})
(u11,u11an,an,{(GB)})
```

As I'm not using `sync_types` in my script, I see no reason why I should generate it except as a workaround for this issue.

Is this a known bug in Pig (or in the local mode of Pig)? Or am I not merging the bags correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still looking for an answer.
I used DISTINCT in Pig version 0.12.x and it seems to work just as expected, however I modified the query as below to achieve your expected result -

```
user_identities = LOAD 'userPig.txt' AS (
    user_id: chararray,
    partner_user_id: chararray,
    partner_user_id_type: chararray,
    sync_types: bag{tuple(chararray)}, 
    synced_first_timestamp: double,
    synced_last_timestamp: double,
    country_codes: bag{tuple(chararray)},
    partner_id: chararray);

    user_identities_filter = foreach user_identities generate user_id,
        partner_user_id,  partner_id, country_codes;

    user_identities_group = GROUP user_identities_filter BY (user_id,
        partner_user_id, partner_id);

    user_stats = FOREACH user_identities_group {
       uniq_country_codes = FOREACH user_identities_filter GENERATE  
           flatten(country_codes);
       uniq_country_codes = DISTINCT uniq_country_codes;
       GENERATE FLATTEN(group), uniq_country_codes AS uniq_coutry_codes;
    }

    DUMP user_stats;
```